# vega lite grouping for pie chart

Tags: vega-lite

how would i find out how many grouping will result from vega-lite? Sample use cases would be: say ..  i want to derive that grouping information to maybe display a message that say "you have too many groupings" or figure out a better color scheme based on number of grouping.
sample vega-lite spec here:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with labels.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "a", "value": 4},
      {"category": "b", "value": 6},
      {"category": "c", "value": 10},
      {"category": "d", "value": 3},
      {"category": "e", "value": 7},
      {"category": "f", "value": 8},{"category": "f", "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true},
    "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"}

  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": {"type": "arc", "outerRadius": 80}
  }, {
    "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 90},
    "encoding": {
      "text": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"}
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is "how can I calculate how many unique items are in the `category` field, you could use `joinaggregate` transform with the `distinct` operator to count.

```json
// ... the rest of your spec
"transform": [
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{
       "op": "distinct",
       "field": "categories",
       "as": "number_of_categories"
      }]
    }
```

In your example, the result would be to add a column `number_of_categories` with a value of `6` to every row in your table.

You can read more about [joinaggregate here](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/joinaggregate.html), and find all the available operators [on the aggregate](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/aggregate.html) page.

Comment: I would like to find out if I can derive `number_of_categories` from spec within code. Would there be a way to derive that info? I'm thinking perhaps with vega View API, but not too sure

Comment: Hi, I think it could be retrieved from the view.dataset() API. Once you retrieve a dataset, number_of_categories would be one of the columns in the rows. See https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_data for more detail.